# How can I best go about approaching this issue of extracting URL links from an RSS feed?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, url, rss

I googled a lot before landing here but I can't find anything that answers my question.

I essentially I want use my windows file manager to browse the latest RSS feeds as URL links that I can open in my own browser. I have my own competent file manager that will label, sort and automate the URL files and have a browser that will display pages exactly how I need them displayed.

Is there a Command line tool that is built to extract latest feed from an RSS and save them as individual URL files?

If not, can I do it with PowerShell?

To me, there does not seem to be more to it than getting latest RSS Feed and outputting them as individual URL files to a directory. Where I may have an issue is determining where the latest feed threshold would be, so I am not recreating duplicate URL files.

Any insight and potential pitfalls into this would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since RSS feeds are straightforward XML, there are command line tools, but you'll have to write a domain-specific language to tell them which element from the XML document to retrieve. Not hard, but a new language to learn.

I don't know in which language your file manager is written, but I'd honestly just look for "XML parser {languagename}" on google. There *is* one, full stop.

Comment: Hey thanks. I am new to this and have a question or two about your answer, I hope you don't mind.

May I ask what you mean by domain specific language? From a brief search, PowerShell seems to have native capabilities to retrieve information wrapped in XML tags as objects. Is this not sufficient?

If not what other language would do? I know some Python and JavaScript and plan to learn more of the two anyways.

Comment: The file manager I use is called [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au) and it is written in C++. I know it uses XML to store some of its config files. Its a pretty complicated tool to try to programmatically interface with, hence why I am trying to do this in PowerShell.

Comment: Yeah, but if it already has access to an XML parser, then you'd want to use that.

Comment: Okay go it. Thanks allot!